# Using R to download a file without a download link

Tags: r, download, onclick

I try to download a csv file programmatically on a webpage.
Here is the [URL](https://e-service.cwb.gov.tw/HistoryDataQuery/MonthDataController.do?command=viewMain&station=466920&stname=%25E8%2587%25BA%25E5%258C%2597&datepicker=2017-02).

I tried to use `download.file()` in R, but there is no link for the csv file.

Can I use R to click the 'CSV' button on top of the webpage to trigger the download process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also directly read the table on the page instead of trying to download the `csv`:

```
library(rvest)
url<-"https://e-service.cwb.gov.tw/HistoryDataQuery/MonthDataController.do?command=viewMain&station=466920&stname=%25E8%2587%25BA%25E5%258C%2597&datepicker=2017-02"
session <- html_session(url)
data <- html_table(session)
head(data[[2]])
```